# Faster, less memory if?

Tags: c++, performance

I was wondering what was faster and used less memory, I would assume its this block but they might be the same:

```
if((X[i] == 0 && Y[i] == 0) ||
    (X[i] == 1 && Y[i] == 1) ||
    (X[i] == 0 && Y[i] == 2) ||
    (X[i] == -1 && Y[i] == 3) ||
    (X[i] == -2 && Y[i] == 2) ||
    (X[i] == -3 && Y[i] == 1) ||
    (X[i] == -4 && Y[i] == 0)) cout << "DA";
```

or maybe its this block:

```
if(X[i] == 0 && Y[i] == 0) cout << "DA";
else if(X[i] == 1 && Y[i] == 1) cout << "DA";
else if(X[i] == 0 && Y[i] == 2) cout << "DA";
else if(X[i] == -1 && Y[i] == 3) cout << "DA";
else if(X[i] == -2 && Y[i] == 2) cout << "DA";
else if(X[i] == -3 && Y[i] == 1) cout << "DA";
else if(X[i] == -4 && Y[i] == 0) cout << "DA";
```

or is there a faster method ? Thanks.

Comment: The second will lead to larger bytecode (if you don't have a very smart compiler) and contains duplicate code, so prefer the first one.

Comment: Fast when running? Fast when compiling? Fast when typing?

Comment: I don't prefer any, use a map/an array or some other data structure.

Comment: Is this a bottleneck in our code? Have you measured?

Comment: It would be interesting if someone did...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is pure speculation.

Comment: This is the only "memory" intensive block in the code and I'm trying to  reduce the memory usage to minimum.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Pardon my being blunt, but unless you're asking that *purely* rhetorically, that's a silly question. This is some logic followed by writing to a stream. Essentially the only reasonable possibility is that the writing to a stream part *will* be the bottleneck, and it's identical between the two code snippets.

Comment: What leads you to conclude that this code is "memory" intensive?  Define "memory" intensive.  Did you mean "takes up a lot of memory?" Or maybe "causes lots of cache misses?" Or something like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both will lead to exactly the same compiled code, if your compiler is worth anything.
Maybe with the exception if you disable all optimization, a case which is simply not interesting to optimize.

Thus, use the clearer code, which if in doubt is the shorter one:
Use the first variation.

If you want to optimize things, consider computing `X[i]` and `Y[i]` only once if they are expensive (unlikely).
Also, you could sort according to likelihood (though probably also not worth it if few enough tests).
What you could also try is changing short-circuiting operators for non-short-circuiting, to avoid jumps (this can backfire).

As an aside, in this case the stream-insertion probably relegates the condition-testing to insignificance, performance-wise.

Comment: First one obviously made it easier to do branch prediction. It only requires one register to store the condition and that condition only leads to one block of code. Stream is a bad example here because it's a heavy function and makes most other optimizations pointless.

Comment: @user3528438: Sorry, but I don't quite understand. How does OPs first option benefit branch-prediction, if it will be compiled the same as as the second? And I treated the stream-insertion as simply an example-operation, though otherwise it will swamp everything else, true.

Comment: "cout << "DA";" is a heavy function call and the the code will be compiled to a conditional jump, in this case, optimizations in the condition expression does not make much sense, and I suspect the compiler will make much effort actually doing optimization. But if the condition leads to something lighter weight, like a few arithmetic operations, it's completely different story.

Answer (score 4):

Let me start by saying that nothing you can do here is likely to make any noticeable difference in speed or memory usage. The simple fact is that the time taken for the logic leading up to the write to `cout` is going to be completely lost in the noise. The write to `cout` itself is going to be such a huge majority of the time, *and* (at least usually) vary so widely that the time for the rest of the logic is 100% irrelevant.

That said, you can almost certainly reduce the rest of the logic a little bit. The first check for x[i] == 0 && y[i] == 0 can be reduced to `x[i] | y[i] == 0`. It looks like the remainder can be reduced to `unsigned(x[i])+4u < 5u && x[i] + y[i] == 2`.

That reduces 6 conditions down to 3 conditions + a tiny bit of math. If this were in a tight loop without any I/O, I'd expect it to be noticeably faster (but with the result being a write to a stream, you probably won't even be able to *measure* a difference dependably, not to mention noticing the difference).

Answer (score 3):

Personally I'd go for the first one for the sake of clarity and little duplication.

Also take advantage of short-cutting: put the most likely cases first.

If X and Y are instances of a class with an expensive overloaded `[]` operator, then precompute `X[i]` and `Y[i]`. Note that `[]` is as cheap as variable access for trival types. If X and Y are instances of a template, then *always* precompute just in case `[]` is expensive for a particular type.